# How to connect three computers on a netowork

Tags: windows, networking

I have three windows PC  connected to each other via a 10/100 Fast ethernet switch. Now I am trying to create a shared area or a means to access each computer from the other.

The three computers are our test environment. So I need a common area to store Screenshots and etc.

Secondly, I need to access the Common Folder or the three computers through laptop which is not on the network. To give you a clearer picture, I primarily need this provision because I need to access the data collected from the test result and document it.

Note: Remote desktop connection is not possible ( as instructed by senior members of the team). I need other ways. I tried the good old Share folder with everyone in the network but didn't work.( What am I doing wrong)

Could someone tell me what are the options that is available to me?

Comment: You want to use sharing/everyone and make it work. The most common problem when creating this kind of share is how you establish permissions. If you right-click on the folder to be shared and select properties --> Share tab -->Advanced sharing-- check the box "share this folder".  Below this is a button that says "permissions" go in there and grant everyone full control.  (Most people don't notice that button.)   OK your way out of there and THEN go to the security tab and setup permissions in there as well.

Comment: @Larryc Thanks. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link for setting up a ftp server

http://techgenix.com/ftp-server-windows-10/

1 of the PC's can be your server and other PC's can access it.

you can use any ftp client to access or put/get your files.